# Moving ASP.NET MVC website to a server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, model-view-controller, server

Ive been developing a website in VS 2013, and been testing it using the built in IIS.

Ive not decided to move it to the server where it will eventually lie.

I have all my dll files in the bin folder, published the project etc, but i still receive

> Internal Error 500

I previously had to downgrade my project from .NET 4.5 to 4.0 because there is no option to upgrade my server. Therefore i had to change alot of the web.config files

Any ideas why i still receive this error?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please        visit
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
 -->
 <configuration>
     <configSections>

         <section name="entityFramework"     type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection,    EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
    <appSettings>
     <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
      <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
      <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
  <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

<httpRuntime />
 </system.web>
  <runtime>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral"   publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization"   publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930"   newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
  <entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory,   EntityFramework">
   <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
   </parameters>
   </defaultConnectionFactory>
   <providers>
   <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"   type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
   </providers>
  </entityFramework>
   <connectionStrings>
   <add name="team06Entities" c  connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DatabaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=co-web;initial catalog=team06;persist security info=True;user id=team06;password=******;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: In *system.web* tag add *<customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>* It will show exact error

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze I realised my sftp wasnt uploading my files correctly. I uploaded them and recieved a page telling me to do exactly what you told me to do. But now i am receiving the same error over and over even after i added the customErrors tag

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze "An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. "    I have since tried again and i just recieve the same as the first time, no specific error?

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze recieving proper errors now, thanks for your help. Seems my sftp client is playing up

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze Actually customErrors mode should be **Off** in order to see the error details remotely. Also, you can use the <httpErrors> tag errorMode="Detailed" to see IIS errors.

Comment: @user2976358 you should use [Webdeploy](http://www.itworld.com/article/2833419/consumerization/if-you-re-developing-in-visual-studio-and-not-using-webdeploy--you-re-doing-it-wrong.html) from Visual Studio instead of FTP, it's reliable and very easy to use.

Comment: @Adrianne yes it should be *off*